# Calcular horas trabalhadas, com botão que adiciona campos no Formulário (JavaScript, HTML)

Tags: javascript, html

estou tentando fazer um sistema para gerenciar as horas trabalhadas dos colaboradores, utilizando somente HTML e JavaScript, gostaria que o gerente possa inserir no sistema de forma dinâmica novas linhas no Formulário. Para isso estou usando o seguinte código.

```html
<div id="origem">

<label for="init">Inicio 1: </label>
<input type="time" name="init" id="entrada1" />

<label for="end">Fim 1: </label>
<input type="time" name="end" id="saida1" />

<label for="end">Inicio 2: </label>
<input type="time" name="end" id="entrada2" />

<label for="end">Fim 2: </label>
<input type="time" name="end" id="saida2" />

<button onclick="calcular();">Calcular</button>


</div>

<span id="resultado"></span>

<div id="destino">
</div>



<button onclick="duplicarCampos();">Duplicar</button>



<script type="text/javascript">

    function duplicarCampos() {
        var clone = document.getElementById('origem').cloneNode(true);
        var destino = document.getElementById('destino');
        destino.appendChild(clone);

        var camposClonados = clone.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (i = 0; i < camposClonados.length; i++) {
            camposClonados[i].value = '';
        }



    }


    function calcular() {
        // Pega os dois inputs do tipo time.
        const entrada1 = document.getElementById("entrada1");

        const saida1 = document.getElementById("saida1");

        const entrada2 = document.getElementById("entrada2");

        const saida2 = document.getElementById("saida2");


        // Pega os valores dos inputs e substitui os dois pontos por uma string vazia,
        // depois faz o cálculo para obter o valor desejado.
        const result = ((saida1.value.replace(":", "") - entrada1.value.replace(":", "")) + (saida2.value.replace(":", "") - entrada2.value.replace(":", ""))) * 5 + "";

        // Pega a metade da string.
        const metade = Math.floor(result.length / 2);

        // Pega a primeira parte da string e concatena ela com os dois pontos,
        // em seguida pega a segunda parte da string e a concatena também.
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML =
            result.substr(0, metade) + ":" + result.substr(metade);
    }
</script>
```

Na primeira linha, eu consigo calcular perfeitamente o que é inserido, entretanto, quando gero uma nova linha a baixo no Formulário, o sistema está pegando as informações digitadas anteriormente, acredito que seja motivado por eu estar clonando as tudo o que está dentro de minha Div, tanto é que se for colocado um alert logo a baixo do campo: `document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = result.substr(0, metade) + ":" + result.substr(metade);`, ele retorna o valor digitado na primeira linha do Formulário, se alguém tiver uma solução para ajustar esse Código agradeço muito.

Answer (score 0):

Para obter a diferença entre dois tempos podemos converter em datas. Para obter a soma faz-se o cálculo.

Não pode haver dois inputs com o mesmo ID por isso usa-se um contador e adiciona-se o HTML dinamicamente.

```
<div id="tempos">

</div>

<button onclick="adicionarCampos();">Adicionar Campos</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var count = 0;

    function get(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function adicionarCampos() {
        count += 1;
        var html = 
            '<label for="init-'+count+'">Inicio 1: </label>' +
            '<input type="time" name="init-'+count+'" id="entrada1-'+count+'" />' +
            '<label for="end'+count+'">Fim 1: </label>' +
            '<input type="time" name="end-'+count+'" id="saida1-'+count+'" />' +
            '<label for="init2-'+count+'">Inicio 2: </label>' +
            '<input type="time" name="init2-'+count+'" id="entrada2-'+count+'" />' +
            '<label for="end2-'+count+'">Fim 2: </label>' +
            '<input type="time" name="end2-'+count+'" id="saida2-'+count+'" />' +
            '<button onclick="calcular(get(\'entrada1-'+count+'\'), get(\'saida1-'+count+'\'), get(\'entrada2-'+count+'\'), get(\'saida2-'+count+'\'), get(\'resultado-'+count+'\'));">Calcular</button>' +
            '<span id="resultado-'+count+'"></span>';

        var campos = document.createElement('div');
        campos.innerHTML = html;

        get("tempos").appendChild(campos);
    }

    function diff(start, end) {
        start = start.split(":");
        end = end.split(":");
        var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
        var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
        var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        var hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
        diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
        var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);

        return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
    }

    function sum(start, end) {
        start = start.split(":");
        end = end.split(":");
        var x1 = parseInt(start[0])*60 + parseInt(start[1]);
        var x2 = parseInt(end[0])*60 + parseInt(end[1]);
        var minutes = x1 + x2;
        var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
        minutes = minutes % 60;

        return (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + ":" + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
    }


    function calcular(entrada1, saida1, entrada2, saida2, resultado) {
        var diff1 = diff(entrada1.value, saida1.value);
        var diff2 = diff(entrada2.value, saida2.value);
        const result = sum(diff1, diff2);
        resultado.innerHTML = result;
    }

    adicionarCampos();
</script>
```